# Controller pode ter métodos privados?

Tags: javascript, html, mvc

Estou com uma dúvida e queria ouvir opinião de mais mais pessoas. Seguindo o *MVC*, um *Controller* pode ter métodos privados?
Essa dúvida me surgiu pois no meu contexto, eu tenho um um *Controller JS*, e minha *View* é uma pagina *HTML*.
Bem, se o *Controller* existe para controlar a *View*, não faz muito sentido ele ter métodos privados, uma vez que a *View* não poderia usar, ou faz sentido sim?!
Talvez eu esteja me confundindo um pouco.

Comment: Qual tecnologia de MVC?

Comment: os métodos privados podem (e devem) existir, até porque eles suportam/auxiliam os métodos públicos, facilitando inclusive a leitura do seu codigo.

Comment: @cigano-morrison-mendez, não entendi a sua pergunta, desculpe!

Comment: @andrepaulo, mas esses métodos privados deveriam ser mais genéricos, não ?! Se sim, não seria mais adequando criar um Utilites e colocar esses métodos?! Isso retiraria funções privadas do controller.

Comment: Aí vc vai ter uma "linguiça" no utilities ...

Comment: @DanielSilveira Perguntei porque, dependendo da tecnologia do MVC (a linguagem, o framework, a convenção, etc), a implementação e a abordagem são completamente diferentes. Responder isso detalhando as várias implementações ficaria gigantesco.

Answer (score 2):

As vezes queremos métodos que só possam ser acessados pelo próprio controller, como cálculos, mudanças de estado, entre outros. Desta forma, a view não terá acesso direto a esses métodos, apenas a partir de outros métodos.